# CSS - Positioning an image alongside text

Tags: html, css

I have a section of a site that needs a small image to sit alongside text for contact information. It needs to look like this - 
[image: PSD version]

At the moment it looks like this - 
[image: Coded version]

I've tried some different positioning aspects but can't seem to fix it. Here's the relevant code so far -

**HTML**

```
<div class="six columns">
                    <h2>To start getting great advice, get in touch.</h2>
                        <div class="phone">
                            <img src="images/phone.png">
                            <p>0113 220 5265</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="email">    
                            <img src="images/email.png">
                            <p>hello@featuremedia.co.uk</p>
                        </div>    
                        <img src="images/Logo.png" style="width:250px;height:30px; margin-top: 20px;">
            </div>
```

**CSS**

```
section#form h2 {
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-top: 40px;
}

.phone {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 100px;

}

.email {
    float: left;

}
```

I still need to re-size the images but my main concern is getting the image to sit correctly alongside the text as in the first image above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since other answers use flexbox or `inline-block`, here's one to use floats as you originally had.

Remember that in your HTML you are trying to float the images and the phone numbers, which are contained within the divs `.phone` and `.email`. So don't float `.phone` and `.email`, float their contents:

```
.phone img, .phone p, .email img, .email p {
  float: left;
}
```

After that it is a matter of margins and also [clearfixing](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) the divs so that they will take the full height of their children and fall into a horizontal column.

```css
section#form h2 {
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
.phone img, .phone p, .email img, .email p {
  float: left;
}
.email {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.phone p, .email p {
  margin: 3px 0 0 10px;
}
.phone::after, .email::after { /*clearfix*/
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="six columns">
  <h2>To start getting great advice, get in touch.</h2>
  <div class="phone">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/25x25">
    <p>0113 220 5265</p>
  </div>
  <div class="email">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/25x25">
    <p>hello@featuremedia.co.uk</p>
  </div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/250x30" style="width:250px;height:30px; margin-top: 20px;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use the following styles:
https://jsfiddle.net/56n074g6/1/

```css
.phone p,
.email p {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 6px;
}

.phone,
.email {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="six columns">
  <h2>To start getting great advice, get in touch.</h2>
  <div class="phone">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/30x30">
    <p>0113 220 5265</p>
  </div>
  <div class="email">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/30x30">
    <p>hello@featuremedia.co.uk</p>
  </div>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x75" style="width:250px;height:30px; margin-top: 20px;">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for converting the answer to a Stack snippet @hungerstar

Comment: One less step for users is always a good thing! i.e. When possible, not having to leave the site to see a working example.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using float on those containers, add `clear: both;` will make sure there is no floating element on the left and right side (take the whole row).

Also `p` is a block element, you can change it to inline or just use a `span`

```css
section#form h2 {
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-top: 40px;
}

.phone {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 100px;
}

.email, .mylogo {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="six columns">
  <h2>To start getting great advice, get in touch.</h2>
  <div class="phone">
    <img src="images/phone.png">
    <span>0113 220 5265</span>
  </div>
  <div class="email">
    <img src="images/email.png">
    <span>hello@featuremedia.co.uk</span>
  </div>
  <div class="mylogo">
    <img src="images/Logo.png" style="width:250px;height:30px; margin-top: 20px;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `display: inline-block` to your img and p elements.

```css
section#form h2 {
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.phone {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 100px;
}

.email {
  float: left;
}

p,
img {
  display: inline-block;
}

/*Extra CSS to mimic your container*/
.six.columns {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="six columns">
  <h2>To start getting great advice, get in touch.</h2>
  <div class="phone">
    <img src="images/phone.png">
    <p>0113 220 5265</p>
  </div>
  <div class="email">
    <img src="images/email.png">
    <p>hello@featuremedia.co.uk</p>
  </div>
  <img src="images/Logo.png" style="width:250px;height:30px; margin-top: 20px;">
</div>
```

Comment: This isn't even how it looks in OP's picture.

Comment: @cjl750 And that's because the OP is using float, and has a container with a smaller width than the snippet. The container is not included with the code provided

Comment: I find it more likely that OP isn't sure how to use floats correctly, which is why he's asking this question in the first place. Even if your guess is right, you could mention in your answer that a container would be necessary to achieve the desired result.

Comment: @CalvT븃 you should clear those floats so everything stacks. That would be the most flexible approach. Reducing the container width might cause the heading to wrap at a desired font size.

Comment: @cjl750 *The container already exists* Note that we don't have the CSS for `<div class="six columns">`. I've updated my answer anyway

Answer (score 0):

it's now easy with flexboxes

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="col">
  <img src="http://www.pngmart.com/files/2/Mario-Transparent-Background.png" style="width: 100px;" />
</div>

<div class="col">
  Hello World
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<style> 
.sameline{display:inline-block}
<\style>

<div>

<div class="sameline">
<img src="" />
</div>

<div class="sameline">
<p>text</p>
</div>

</div>
```

This will work perfectly fine

Comment: What's the point of wrapping each element in a DIV? Why not apply the class directly to the elements themselves?

Comment: First check whether it will work or not then degrade the answer

Comment: FYI, I didn't down vote. Just pointing out this solution has superfluous markup.

Comment: Yes you are doing good buddy. I just thought to give an answer .